How can I derive these formulas?
For inductor design, I referred to this document, which states the following:

How are equations (17) and (18) derived?
What is Kc? Okay, I know it's the Crest Factor, but what is it exactly?

Would those equations be based on equations 13, 14 and 15?

I’m not sure exactly. I almost managed to derive it, but the only difference is that in my formula, the factor of 2 in the numerator moved to the denominator. As for Kc , it’s supposedly Kc = Imax/Irms.
